# jsf composite component nested EL

Tags: jsf, el, composite-component

hi i want to pass a bean as parameter composite component,
then i will call its function as an action.

```
<cc:attribute required="true"   name="daobean" />

<ui:param name="daobeann" value="#{cc.attrs.daobean}" />
<p:commandButton action="#{daobeann.update}" />
```

and i use the component as

```
 <util:mycomponent daobean="mybean" />
```

but i get mybean.update() not found.

How can i call update method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui:param` is for templating purposes.
You don't need it here.

Just use  correct composite interface and implementation

```
<cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute required="true" name="daobean" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
     <p:commandButton action="#{cc.attributes.daobean.update}" />
</cc:implementation>
```

Then reference it from parent page like

`<util:mycomponent daobean="#{mybean}" />`